# Provide Last-Event-Id to EventSource constructor

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events, eventsource

Is it possible to set the Last-Event-Id header of an EventSource ? I have a simple chat app that keeps the messages cached. When I connect, I send all the chat since the Last-Event-Id, or all of them if it is not provided.

Since I keep the messages, I figured I might be able to pass the Id to the EventSource constructor to avoid it giving me back all the messages I already have. Is that simply not possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass information on the query string.

```
var source = EventSource("source?eventId=12345");
```

Ultimately it is just up to you to make sense of it on the server side and return the correct event(s).

Comment: Well I guess I'll accept this answer, but it kinds sucks I have two places to get the last event ID from :(

Comment: @roblabla - I understand. It is because you are trying to use the technology in a way that is not quite how it is intended. It is supposed to be used for getting updates on future changes. Not the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

The EventSource request will only have the `Last-Event-Id` header if the connection breaks and the client will have to reconnect. You can "force" this reconnection by letting the server break the first connection.

It goes like this:

1. Create a connection using EventSource.
2. The server receives the request and test if the `Last-Event-Id` is a request header.

   - If the `Last-Event-Id` is present:

     - get the value/id.
     - send events from the server according to the id.
   - If the `Last-Event-Id` is not present:

     - send an event containing an id (the id that you consider to be the last id).
     - make the server break/finish the connection.
3. If the connection is broken by the server the client will try to reconnect with a new request. This time the request will have a `Last-Event-Id` header, and now you jump up to number 2.

The only problem with this approach is the delay caused by the client because it has to make two connections. I haven't tested the delay, but it looks like something around 3-5 seconds between each request.

Comment: In the first request, you could use the `retry` field to change the delay. For instance send `retry: 0` to change the delay to `0ms`. (I'm not sure if 0 is valid. The spec doesn't mention it)